# Simulate a matricies of data using R as bands of satellite imagery from scratch

Tags: r, matrix, rgb, simulate

I am trying to 
1)  Simulate a matrix of data using R (in effect an image of numbers where each cell in the matrix has a number on the numerical scale of 0-255 (8 bit data))

2)  Map the simulated data using mapping tools

3)  Classify the image into 8-10 classes

The idea is to use a simple function to generate an image with 3 bands of Red Green and Blue imagery simulating multispectral imagery from satellite. So a composite of 3 different matricies. Like this.

[image: Example]

Then classify the composite by colour into 8 or 10 classes
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is what i have been trying to acheive                                                                       #red band                                                                                               Band1<-matrix(sample(0:255, 100, replace = FALSE), ncol = 10)
#green band                                                                                       Band2<-matrix(sample(0:255, 100, replace = FALSE), ncol = 10)
#blue band                                                                                       Band3<-matrix(sample(0:255, 100, replace = FALSE), ncol = 10)

Comment: But now I am trying to change the numberical values into RGB colours then plot the combined bands as a single image.

Comment: So what im trying to do here is to essentially evenly split the 0-255 rgb colours into 8-10

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/GUID-9C81871D-F349-473E-8D24-FA0B6F235EFE-web.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is an approach to sample as a gradient.

```
imagerows <- 100
imagecols <- 100
cuts <- 8
(imagecols * imagerows) %% cuts == 0 #Must be true
colorgroups <- as.integer(cut(0:255,cuts))
colors <- c("red","green","blue")
result <- lapply(colors,function(y){
  unlist(
    lapply(seq(1,cuts),function(x){sample((0:255)[colorgroups == x],
                                  size = (imagerows*imagecols)/cuts,
                                  replace = TRUE)})
    )})
```

`result` is now a list of length `3`, each element of which is a 100x100 matrix. The matrix contains 100 * 100 random samples between `0` and `255`, but in `cuts` number of increasing groups.

We can then control the direction of the gradient using `byrow =` in `matrix` and by using `rev()` on the data.

```
red.matrix <-   matrix((result[[1]]),nrow=imagerows,ncol=imagecols,byrow = TRUE)
green.matrix <-   matrix((result[[2]]),nrow=imagerows,ncol=imagecols,byrow = FALSE)
blue.matrix <-   matrix(rev(result[[3]]),nrow=imagerows,ncol=imagecols,byrow = FALSE)
```

Then we put the colors together with `rgb()` which outputs a vector. We can coerce it back into a matrix by assigning dimensions. Then just plot with `grid.raster()`.

```
library(grid)
rgb.matrix <- rgb(red.matrix,green.matrix,blue.matrix,maxColorValue = 255)
dim(rgb.matrix) <- c(imagerows,imagecols)
grid.newpage()
grid.raster(rgb.matrix,interpolate = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Ian, thanks again, is this image a composite of 3 different matrices? or is it a single matrix. This probably helps explain what im trying to do better. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/GUID-9C81871D-F349-473E-8D24-FA0B6F235EFE-web.gif

Comment: Is there a way to plot this like a map as to add a scale and legend title etc?

Comment: I think that might be too broad for a single question. Each of 1-3 in your original question, in fact, is very broad. You could consider opening a new question.